# Azure Container Registry - List Images / Tags - Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-container-registry

I'm bashing my head against the wall to try and figure out how to programmatically get a list of images in an Azure Container Registry.

Everything seems to fall down to looking in Docker.DotNet's own *local* instantiation of an image list, and push/pulling to an ACR via that local repository - but nothing is showing me how to get a list of images (and their tags) from the ACR itself.      In digging through their rest API for azure, it looks like only a slim set of "management" options are available (getting a list of ACRs, getting the properties of an ACR, but nothing shows me it dives deeper than that).

I can get a list of image names, and then their image name tags via the Azure CLI -- **but** I'm looking to get an enumerable list of images in a C# app (inside a web-api, matter of fact).

Essentially - what I want to do is have a list of running images remotely, in docker -- and compare *those* to what's up in the ACR, to give a "hey, there's a newer version of this image available".

Has anyone done this?   To any effect?

Is it simple like this (for Docker):

```
    var _credentials = new BasicAuthCredentials("MY_REG_USERNAME", "MY_REG_PASSWORD");
    var _config = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("MY_REGISTRY_NAME.azurecr.io"), _credentials);
    DockerClient _client = _config.CreateClient();

    var myList = await _client.Images.ListImagesAsync(
             new Docker.DotNet.Models.ImagesListParameters() { All = true }
     );
```

or impossible?

I've messed around with IoT hubs and getting device twin lists and the like, with the DeviceClient -- is there nothing like this for the ACR?

Comment: Can you please refer this documentation from Microsoft, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/acr-dotnet-manage-azure-container-registry

Comment: That doesn't speak to what I'd asked.   It demonstrates listing images in a local docker instance, and pushing it to an ACR -- but nothing in there lets you iterate the ACR itself.    I want to know the image/tags in the ACR, not the local Docker.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am also "bashing my head against the wall" for this one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was facing the same puzzle for a while and the answer is:

**For image operations (including the tag list you were asking about) Microsoft supports the docker registry API v2.**

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api

What does it mean? An Example:

Azure REST API is for Azure resource operations only. There you can use Bearer Token authentication and for example make a GET request like this:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubscriptionGUID/resourceGroups/ContainerRegistry/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/YourRegistryName?api-version=2017-10-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%3CSubscriptionGUID%3E/resourceGroups/ContainerRegistry/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/YourRegistryName?api-version=2017-10-01)

But as you already know this will not give you access to operations on the content of the ACR.

Instead you need to call a different end-point, namely the Registry end-point, and very importantly, you need to use basic authentication with username and password:

[https://yourregistryname-on.azurecr.io/v2/imagename/tags/list](https://yourregistry-on.azurecr.io/v2/%3Cimagename%3E/tags/list)

What username and password is it? Well, there are 2 types possible:

1. The admin user you can enable on the ACR in the Azure portal
2. You can configure users in the ACR under Access Control with different types of access (more secure). As the username you can use the underlying GUID, visible in the query string in the URL when selecting it in Azure portal. Password/key can be configured there as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog URL with basic authentication.
To get username and password for basic auth, use below command from Powershell.

**az acr credential show --name myregistry**

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal to use from within .NET, another CLI-centric way to get all the images is using `az acr manifest` (the successor to `az acr repository show-manifests`). This lists all the images, whether tagged or not, present in a given repository. For example:

```bash
MY_REGISTRY=<name of your registry>
MY_REPOSITORY=<name of your repository>

az acr manifest list-metadata \
  --registry $MY_REGISTRY \
  --name $MY_REPOSITORY \
  --query '[:].[digest, imageSize, tags[:]]' \
  -o table
```

Shows every image digest, size, and list of tags associated with that image, whether tagged or not.