# How can I get Docker image tag info for azureml base images?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently using the **mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:latest** docker image.

To access the list of all tags from **mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base** I do a GET request to
http://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/azureml/base/tags/list according to instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50326027/4039897), and what I see is.

```
{
  "name": "azureml/base",
  "tags": [
    "0.1",
    "0.1.1",
    "0.1.2",
    "0.1.3",
    "0.1.4",
    "0.1.5",
    "0.2.0",
    "0.2.1",
    "0.2.2",
    "0.2.3",
    "0.2.4",
    "0.4.0",
    "intelmpi",
    "intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04",
    "latest",
    "openmpi",
    "openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu16.04"
  ]
}
```

I see that there are different version tags (check below), however I would like to know what the numbered tags mean, if they are supported and how frequently all tags get updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this helps, but apparently until recently Microsoft wasn't opensourcing details about those images.
However, following https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25242, you can see part of the information - say, created dates - (e.g. on 0.2.4) via

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:0.2.4
docker inspect mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:0.2.4
```

or

```
docker history --no-trunc mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:0.2.4
```

for more recent images, you can follow updates and get support by filing issues on https://github.com/Azure/AzureML-Containers

Comment: It seems as the `docker inspect` command only works for the latest tag. Do you see the same thing?

Comment: @muzio Works for me if I `docker pull` beforehand. I am editing my answer accordingly. However, refer to the answer by Billy Hu: those old tags are not supported.

Comment: Great! Thank you @Davide!

Answer (score 1):

Those versioned tags are out-dated tags and they don't get support anymore.

Please use stable tags like "latest", "intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04" instead. All featured tags mentioned in below link will be updated on a regular basis.

https://github.com/Azure/AzureML-Containers